# How to make handler specially for out of memory situation in php?

Tags: php

I need something like

```
register_error_handler(MEMORY_LEAK, 'function_that_handles_that');
```

Is there something like this? Or do I have to manually check for memory to do some sort of memory cleange? I have parsing situation that can get 1GB of ram after 7000 entries, but somehow I know how to reduce current memory usage in function, but I don't want to call it every time in loop.

Comment: I think memory error is not catchable (you need even more memory to throw error). Try manage your data more wisely.

Comment: The fact error is not catchable doesn't mean there is no workaround...

Comment: It's been allocating something useless anyway, got it into less than 32MB :D

Answer (score 0):

So calling $memcheck->run() at the beging of loop can somehow... Solve the situation.
//not tested

```
<?php 
    namespace utility;
    class memcheck {

        protected static $instance;

        public static function i() {
            if (!isset(static::$instance)) {
                static::$instance = new static();
            }
            return static::$instance;
        }

        private function __construct() {
            $this->cleanup_after = (str_replace('m', '', strtolower($GLOBALS['s']['memory']['cleanup_after'])))*1024*1024;
            $this->shutdown_after = (str_replace('m', '', strtolower($GLOBALS['s']['memory']['max'])))*1024*1024;
        public function run() {
            $allocated_memory = memory_get_usage(true);
            $cleanup = ( $allocated_memory > $this->cleanup_after );
            $shutdown = ( $allocated_memory > $this->shutdown_after );
            $allocated_memory = $allocated_memory/1024/1024;
            if( $cleanup ) { 
                if( $shutdown ) {
                    echo 'Too much memory in use '.$allocated_memory.'M -> shutting down';
                    $this->shutdown();
                } else {
                    echo 'Too much memory in use '.$allocated_memory.'M -> cleaning up';
                    $this->cleanup();
                    $allocated_memory = memory_get_usage(true)/1024/1024;
                    echo 'Allocated memory reduced to '.$allocated_memory/1024/1024.;
                }
            }

        }
        private function shutdown() {

        }
        private function cleanup() {

        }
    }
    ?>
```